# C#/WinForms: GroupBox border not drawing until resize when using WS_EX_COMPOSITED

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, groupbox

I have a Form on which I have a TabControl which in turn contains a GroupBox. I have set the `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` extended style in the form's overridden CreateParams method in order to reduce flickering during resizes.

The problem is that when I have `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` enabled, the GroupBox's border is not drawn until I resize the form. I have tried customizing the GroupBox and applying several different styles to try to resolve this but none of the following styles I have tried had any effect:

- `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`
- `WS_CLIPCHILDREN`
- `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get that border to draw properly from the get go?

Comment: i've just tried it myself without a problem. could you send the InitializeComponent code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I created a simple WinForms app ([VS2008 solution here](http://www.fileserve.com/file/s3Sddmq)) that reproduces this behavior for me. Apparently all it takes is a form with the WS_EX_COMPOSITED style and a group box. I am targeting .NET 3.5.

Comment: Looks familiar, attribution is required here.  I've been hearing complaints about this but no repro on this one either.  Not documenting the Windows version and theming options doesn't provide any lead whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry -- Windows XP Pro SP3 32-bit, Windows classic theming.